# PostgreSQL full text search across multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I have a requirement that need to support autocomplete from UI and search across multiple tables for possible match. For example, I have 2 tables: Recipe and Ingredient. When a user types in 'Chicken', it should return all recipe that contains 'Chicken' and all ingredients that contain 'Chicken' (e.g. minced chicken, diced chicken, etc).

I think I need to use full text search but I am quite new to this. I can find many examples online that show how to do it for a single table, but not across multiple tables. Do I need to extract contents from multiple tables into a separate table just for search? Or does postgres support full text search across tables?

Comment: No, you just need to run two queries. It will be twice as slow.

Comment: How will this work if I want to get top 10 results sort by relevance?

Comment: Get the top ten from both tables and use `UNION`.

Comment: Cool, I'll give that a try